# How can I install pydotplus in Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am following along an Edureka video from 2020 about random forest models in Python in preparation for a data science internship.   I am trying to follow the speaker's code, but I am running into an issue when I copied his

**import pydotplus**

code.   Here is the code I tried instead after some searching.   It is the first block that was not giving me a syntax error, but it seems to be taking an indefinite amount of time to run.

**import sys
!{sys.executable} - m pip install pydotplus**

Any ideas on how I can improve the code?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*
I think I found the issue.

**pip install pydotplus**

should work.   I think I just needed to refresh the kernel and run everything again!

Comment: So you know, you can use the magic `pip` and `conda` **inside a cell in the notebook** to insure the packages get installed into the enivronment backing the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Automagics are usually on by default and so the `%` symbol gets added generally behind-the-scenes and the magic command used, equivalent to `%pip install pydotplus`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one works best:

```
import sys
```

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pydotplus
```